# extending phpcodesniffer to filter report based on error codes

Tags: php, pear, phpcodesniffer

I am trying to extend PHPCodeSniffer.What I am trying to achive is to filter the report using error codes.

To explain this lets say I have an error message like "error code : 630 , function is not compatible"

When I run PHPCS from command line , I shoudl be able to pass an argument "error code" so that the report is filtered based on it.(only show result for error code say 630)

e.g.

```
 $ phpcs --standard=mystanderd /path/to/code/myfile.php --errorcode=603
```

and output will be

```
FILE: /path/to/code/myfile.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 4 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | ERROR   | 603 | function is  not compatible      
 20 | ERROR   | 603 | function is  not compatible      
 51 | ERROR   | 603 | function is  not compatible      
 88 | ERROR   | 603 | function is  not compatible      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

what is the best way to achive it ?  as far as what I have understood we can filter only based on seviority as it have inbuilt support.

I would like to avoid modifying the core of `PHPCodeSniffer`. What I am thinking to do is to write a wrapper script which will accept the argument from CLI and execute PHPCS the capture the o/p and manipulate it before throwing out to the console.However, I don't think it is a best solution.

Comment: You might get more answers to this (and other?) questions if you responded to the answers that have been given so far...

Answer (score 0):

a bash script utilising grep and wc comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a PHP script like this (let's say this is called my_wrapper.php):

```
<?php

$legal_codes = array(
    '603' => true
);

$f = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
while ($line = fgets($f)) {
    if (preg_match("/^\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*([A-Z]+)\s*\|\s*(\d+)\s*\|\s*(.*)/", $line, $match)) {
        $code = trim($match[3]);
        if (!isset($legal_codes[$code])) {
            continue;
        }
    }
    echo $line;
}

?>
```

Which when called like this:

```
php my_wrapper.php < cs_out.txt
```

With cs_out.txt like this:

```
FILE: /path/to/code/myfile.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 4 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  2 | ERROR   | 601 | function is  not compatible
 20 | ERROR   | 602 | function is  not compatible
 51 | ERROR   | 603 | function is  not compatible
 88 | ERROR   | 604 | function is  not compatible
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Produces output like this:

```
FILE: /path/to/code/myfile.php
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
FOUND 4 ERROR(S) AFFECTING 4 LINE(S)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 51 | ERROR   | 603 | function is  not compatible      
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Making the keys of the $legal_codes array specifiable via command line parameter to my_wrapper.php is left as an exercise for the reader.